# Export TMP Password

Tags: powershell, bitlocker

Many computers were bitlocker with this command:

```
Enable-BitLocker -MountPoint $env:SystemDrive -EncryptionMethod Aes128 -TpmProtector -SkipHardwareTest
```

The previous guy didn't export any recovery keys. Which is causing problems when the motherboard is damaged. Any idea how to export those recovery keys? I have around 300 machines.

One method I found online was:

```
PS C:\> Get-BitLockerVolume | Enable-BitLocker -EncryptionMethod Aes128 -RecoveryKeyPath "NetworkDrive:\Recovery\$name" -RecoveryKeyProtector
```

Whoever, what I am reading tells me that the bitlocked drive will need access to that network drive when booting. Which doesn't work when the end user doesn't have access to the drive at home (Laptop).

Comment: If it is a domain comp, sometimes you can grab the recovery key from AD. Have to View> enable users.computers, etc and advanced features, then find the PC in the tree, then there is a bitlocker tab I think ref: https://www.top-password.com/blog/find-bitlocker-recovery-key-from-active-directory/

Comment: @Narzard I have enabled this feature in our domain. However, 100 are off domain.

Comment: On these machines, you are able to get into windows or no? A workaround to the second command is to make a local share and save to that. Then the user will have to send it to you or youll have to remote to grab it off. Pre 2nd command above with something like `New-Item -ItemType "directory" -Path "c:\temp\recovery"` and then `PS C:\>New-SmbShare -Name "RecoveryKey" -Path "C:\temp\Recovery" -FullAccess "domain\user"`